# Easiest way to package a directory of MATLAB scripts into a Launchpad PPA

Tags: ppa, launchpad, deb, package-management, matlab

I'm administering a small network of Ubuntu boxes for a series of measuring machines in a laboratory. These machines depend on a small directory of MATLAB scripts in /usr/local/MATLAB/... in order to properly read data from a serial device.

I would like to be able to maintain this bit of code on Launchpad so that I could easily package this MATLAB script directory into a PPA and thus, easily maintain all of the computers in the lab...

So, I guess this could also be a Debain/Launchpad question, but -shrugs-.

I'm ready to upload the code to Launchpad and setup a ./debian directory... My question would be, what is the best way to package this simple directory of scripts so that it can work with Launchpad's auto-package system? Seems like there are a number of ways to do this? What's the best way to handle the debian directory? What's the best way to skin the cat?

I have experience doing this with other source code, and have maintained other projects through Launchpad. But never done anything as simple as "just put this directory into '/usr/local/MATLAB'. I also realize that I would not be able to put MATLAB as a dependence of this package of custom scripts.

Does this make sense?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the documentation in Debian New Maintainer's Guide: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html (chapter 4).

Also, take a look at the package `anarchism` for insight:

```
apt-get source anarchism
```

whose `./debian` directory contents should very closely follow what your project needs. Making necessary changes or rolling your own `control`, `copyright`, `changelog` and `rules` is sufficient for building a debian package (issue `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`).

Answer (score 0):

You could run a local repo and when you update the package on your PPA etc it will be marked as an update on your servers, downloaded and installed

Comment: Indeed, as I explain, this is my goal. My question is about the best way to setup the ./debian/ directory for packaging.